# Как в кратком анонсе фильма обыграть "фабрику грёз", которая синоним Голливуду?

Tags: пунктуация

[Фабрика грёз](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_wingwords/2857/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Образная (ироническая) характеристика киностудий Голливуда (США), встречающаяся с 1920-х гг. Автор выражения неизвестен.

> Фильм совместного производства России и Ирландии – «Лестница света»,
> режиссёра и сценариста Джерарда Майкла МакКарти, рассказывает историю
> одиннадцатилетнего мальчишки, который заблудился на Фабрике грёз.
> Проводником между главным героем и миром взрослых, между мечтой и
> реальностью, оказывается девушка Ольга, которую играет Инга Ильм.

Как тут быть со знаками? Ведь если убрать всё к чертям - не будет ли затруднений с восприятием:

*Фильм совместного производства России и Ирландии «Лестница света»
режиссёра и сценариста Джерарда Майкла МакКарти рассказывает историю
одиннадцатилетнего мальчишки, который заблудился на «фабрике грёз».*

Может, слова попереставлять? Подскажите, как лучше?

*Фильм «Лестница света» (Россия–Ирландия) режиссёра и сценариста Джерарда Майкла МакКарти рассказывает историю
одиннадцатилетнего мальчишки, который заблудился на «фабрике грёз».*

Как пишется в скобках совместное производство стран? Тире с отбивкми?

Comment: Извините, но обращаюсь к Вам, как к автору вопроса. А почему "встречающееся"? Разве не так нужно: "...характеристика.., встречающАЯся..."?

Comment: Римма, это ж цитата! Я ж их не читаю! См. самую верхнюю *фабрику грёз* - приведёт к словарям на Академике!

Comment: Да я и ТАМ тоже смотрела, по ссылке... Мне кажется, что на цитаты тоже надо обращать внимание. Это ведь ВАШ вопрос. Так - не читая -  можно "напоссылать"...

Comment: Нет уж, я бесплатно не читаю! ))) Вот если б я правило с ошибкой приводила, тогда да. А у меня - просто пояснение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, без отбивки только предел "от-до"

http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs/index-72634.html?page=16

Мне нравится этот вариант:

Фильм совместного производства России и Ирландии «Лестница света» режиссёра и сценариста Джерарда Майкла МакКарти рассказывает историю одиннадцатилетнего мальчишки, который заблудился на «фабрике грёз».

А почему в названии вопроса "фабрика звёзд"? Речь-то ведь идёт о киностудии "Ленфильм", где перемешиваются воображаемая  и реальная жизнь  мальчика.По-моему, это совсем другое, с "Фабрикой звёзд" никак не соотносится, вот с грёзами - да.

Comment: Я фильм-то не смотрела... Так что делать с ленфильмовской "фабрикой"? В кавычках, две строчные?

Comment: Да, в кавычках и оба слова со строчной, это перифраза, описательный оборот, это ж не название.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, все варианты без скобок тяжелы для восприятия. А в скобки я бы поставил все "выходные данные" этого фильма или только имя режисера как менее важное из двух.

Между Россией и Ирландией я бы поставил тире:
§ 179. Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими именами собственными, совокупностью которых называется какое-либо учение, научное учреждение и т. п., например: Физический закон Бойля – Мариотта.

"фабрика звезд" - со строчной и в кавычках.

**Фильм «Лестница света» (Россия – Ирландия, режиссёр и сценарист Джерард Майкл МакКарти) рассказывает историю одиннадцатилетнего мальчишки, который заблудился на «фабрике грёз».**

или

**Фильм «Лестница света» совместного производства России и Ирландии (режиссёр и сценарист Джерард Майкл МакКарти) рассказывает историю одиннадцатилетнего мальчишки, который заблудился на «фабрике грёз».**